# Line Chart with surrounded ranged area

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart, linechart

I am new to JasperReports and I'm using Jaspersoft Studio 6. I want to have the attached figure (Line chart with two Series Red Line and Blue line with same Categories) and Surrounded Ranged area for the Categories (light blue).

Is it possible to have such report?

Any ideas are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Looking at the [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html), you might be able to create an _overlaid chart_ that includes an _area chart_ and two _line charts_.

Comment: Thank you for your hint, I actually managed to do it using "Projected Values - Test" sample in the demo.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do it using the [`DeviationRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/DeviationRenderer.html) example entitled *Projected Values—Test*, as seen among the *Time Series Charts* in the [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html), with some modification, of course, to fit my requirements.

[image]